# Extract Cumulative N-grams Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an array of words:

```
x=['ae' ; 'be' ; 'ce' ; 'de' ; 'ee' ; 'fe']
```

I would like to extract sets of characters. So assume each set has N = 2 words, how can I go about getting return values that look like this

```
'ae' 'be'
'be' 'ce'
'ce' 'de'
'de' 'ee'
'ee' 'fe'
```

So if N = 2, I get back a matrix where each row contains pairs of the current and previous characters. If N=3 i will get back current and previous 2 chars for each row. I want to avoid loops if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**Circulant Matrix**](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html#f84-1019317) Maltlab provides, truncate it as needed and use it as an index vector:

```
x = {'ae' ; 'be' ; 'ce' ; 'de' ; 'ee' ; 'fe'}
N = 3;

n = numel(x);

A = gallery('circul',n:-1:1)
B = fliplr( A(1:n-N+1,n-N+1:end) )

result = x(B)
```

or a little shorter:

```
A = fliplr( gallery('circul',n:-1:1) )
result = x( A(1:n-N+1,1:n-N) )
```

**or another option using the `hankel`-Matrix:**

```
A = hankel(1:n,1:N)
result = x( A(1:n-N+1,:) )
```

gives:

```
result = 

    'ae'    'be'    'ce'
    'be'    'ce'    'de'
    'ce'    'de'    'ee'
    'de'    'ee'    'fe'
```

Comment: sorry for taking this long, i totally forgot.